# R: combine lists without changing element names

Tags: r

I have two `caretList` objects (models trained using `caretEnsemble` which return a list of `caret` objects). Let's call them `models1` and `models2`.

I would like to concatenate the lists to have a single list of all the model objects:

```
c(model1, model2)
```

The problem is that this appends numbers to the end of the model names. So, if `model1` was a named list of `rf` and `nnet` models, and if `model2` contained `knn`, the concatenation results in:

```
names(c(model1, model2))
```

> [1] "rf1"      "nnet2"      "knn3"

How do I avoid the numbered suffixes?

Comment: In the most basic example, this is not reproducible: `temp <- list(a=5, b=rnorm(10)); temp2 <- list(c="t"); c(temp, temp2)` returns a list with 3 elements, a, b, and c. Maybe there is an underlying mode for `c` for `caret` objects. You might check for the existence of `c.caret` or whatever `class(model1)` returns. As a sidenote, the function that produces the numbers is probably `make.unique`.

Comment: Your hint helped: `c.caretList` explicitly adds numbers to make sure the names are unique, regardless of whether they were already unique or not. https://github.com/zachmayer/caretEnsemble/blob/master/R/S3GenericExtenstions.R
Oh well. In the simple case of just adding one unique model I can get my desired behavior with: `models1$knn <- models2$knn`

Comment: Note that you can also remove the numbers afterward using `gsub("\\d+$", "", names(myList))`, but you want to be sure that there won't be duplicate names.